# a diff for nested dicts without converting to sets

Tags: python, json, recursion, diff

This will be on my radar for the next few months of things to figure out.
It's a pretty interesting challenge. Could be used in many contexts for systems that pass around a lot of json data.

I made a unittest with the expected outputs for each method. 
If someone has any advice on a good algorithm or technique to solve this, 
that alone would help tremendously.

or if you're feeling ambitious, you could solve it for me :-)

```
class Diff():
    """
    Show the difference between two given dicts 'old' and 'new'.

    Intended to be used in an auditing system that checks existing
    records in a nosql database ('old') and compares them with a
    request to update the record ('new') and store the difference
    in a separate database.

    See test_diff.py for expected output for each method.

    Will need recursive methods for nested dicts

    Use dot notation for the path to the key that is different e.g. {"a.b.c": "modified value"}

    Must not convert dicts to sets. Because of the billions of records that will be compared,
    conversion to sets, then back to dicts would drastically slow down the process.
    """

    def added(self, old, new):
        pass

    def modified(self, old, new):
        pass

    def deleted(self, old, new):
        pass

    def difference(self, old, new):
        pass

    def has_key(self, key):
        """explicitly defined for python 2/3 compatability"""
        try:
            self[key]
        except KeyError:
            return False
        return True
```

And here is the unittest

```
import unittest
from diff import Diff

class TestDiff(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.old_dict = {"dict1":{"dict2": {"x":"A","z":"d"}}}
        self.new_dict = {"dict1":{"dict2": {"x":"C","y":"B"}}}
        self.d = Diff()

    def test_added_logic(self):
        result = self.d.added(self.old_dict, self.new_dict)
        expected = {"operation": "ADDED", "field": "dict1.dict2.y", "new": "B"}
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)

    def test_modified_logic(self):
        result = self.d.modified(self.old_dict, self.new_dict)
        expected = {"operation": "MODIFIED", "field": "dict1.dict2.x", "old": "A", "new": "C"}
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)

    def test_deleted_logic(self):
        result = self.d.deleted(self.old_dict, self.new_dict)
        expected = {"operation": "DELETED", "field": "dict1.dict2.z", "old": "d"}
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)

    def test_difference_logic(self):
        result = self.d.difference(self.old_dict, self.new_dict)
        expected = {"results":[
                        {"operation": "ADDED", "field": "dict1.dict2.y", "new": "B"},
                        {"operation": "MODIFIED", "field": "dict1.dict2.x", "old": "A", "new": "C"},
                        {"operation": "DELETED", "field": "dict1.dict2.z", "old": "d"}
            ]
        }
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: how are you comparing? Do all the dicts have the same structure just with different keys?

Answer (score 0):

I took a stab at it and passed the unit test. Ran in Python 2.7. However I changed the unit test expectations to be more uniform, it now always wants a list of dict objects. Otherwise the first three tests wouldn't make sense for multiple differences, and the last one was inconsistent.

Suggestions for improvement are welcome...

```
class Diff():
    """
    Show the difference between two given dicts 'old' and 'new'.

    Intended to be used in an auditing system that checks existing
    records in a nosql database ('old') and compares them with a
    request to update the record ('new') and store the difference
    in a separate database.

    See test_diff.py for expected output for each method.

    Will need recursive methods for nested dicts

    Use dot notation for the path to the key that is different e.g. {"a.b.c": "modified value"}

    Must not convert dicts to sets. Because of the billions of records that will be compared,
    conversion to sets, then back to dicts would drastically slow down the process.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.depth = []
        self.results = []

    def added(self, old, new):
        for key in new:
            if key not in old:
                self.results.append({
                    'operation': 'ADDED',
                    'field': '.'.join(self.depth) + '.' + str(key),
                    'new': new[key]
                })
            elif type(old[key]) == dict and type(new[key]) == dict:
                self.depth.append(str(key))
                self.added(old[key], new[key])

        if self.depth:
            self.depth.pop()
        else:
            return self.results

    def modified(self, old, new):
        for key in [key for key in new if key in old]:
            if type(old[key]) == dict and type(new[key]) == dict:
                self.depth.append(str(key))
                self.modified(old[key], new[key])
            elif old[key] != new[key]:
                self.results.append({
                    'operation': 'MODIFIED',
                    'field': '.'.join(self.depth) + '.' + str(key),
                    'old': old[key],
                    'new': new[key]
                })

        if self.depth:
            self.depth.pop()
        else:
            return self.results

    def deleted(self, old, new):
        for key in old:
            if key not in new:
                self.results.append({
                    'operation': 'DELETED',
                    'field': '.'.join(self.depth) + '.' + str(key),
                    'old': old[key]
                })
            elif type(old[key]) == dict and type(new[key]) == dict:
                self.depth.append(str(key))
                self.deleted(old[key], new[key])

        if self.depth:
            self.depth.pop()
        else:
            return self.results

    def difference(self, old, new):
        self.added(old, new)
        self.modified(old, new)
        self.deleted(old, new)
        return self.results

import unittest
from diff import Diff

class TestDiff(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.old_dict = {"dict1":{"dict2": {"x":"A","z":"d"}}}
        self.new_dict = {"dict1":{"dict2": {"x":"C","y":"B"}}}
        self.d = Diff()

    def test_added_logic(self):
        result = self.d.added(self.old_dict, self.new_dict)
        expected = [{"operation": "ADDED", "field": "dict1.dict2.y", "new": "B"}]
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)

    def test_modified_logic(self):
        result = self.d.modified(self.old_dict, self.new_dict)
        expected = [{"operation": "MODIFIED", "field": "dict1.dict2.x", "old": "A", "new": "C"}]
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)

    def test_deleted_logic(self):
        result = self.d.deleted(self.old_dict, self.new_dict)
        expected = [{"operation": "DELETED", "field": "dict1.dict2.z", "old": "d"}]
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)

    def test_difference_logic(self):
        result = self.d.difference(self.old_dict, self.new_dict)
        expected = [
            {"operation": "ADDED", "field": "dict1.dict2.y", "new": "B"},
            {"operation": "MODIFIED", "field": "dict1.dict2.x", "old": "A", "new": "C"},
            {"operation": "DELETED", "field": "dict1.dict2.z", "old": "d"}
        ]
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Mike, you are awesome. This is perfect. I messed with this for 2 hours last night and felt like my brain was melting. I'll be studying your methods.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to mike.k for solving this**
I've modified the code a little.
I added tests for flat, one level deep dicts.
I also fixed the dot preceding the depth for flat dicts.
Lastly, because the output will be converted to json
to be stored in a database, I added one more method just to 
convert the final difference to a dict.

```
class Diff():
    """
    Show the difference between two given dicts 'old' and 'new'.

    Intended to be used in an auditing system that checks existing
    records in a nosql database ('old') and compares them with a
    request to update the record ('new') and store the difference
    in a separate database.

    See test_diff.py for expected output for each method.

    Will need recursive methods for nested dicts

    Use dot notation for the path to the key that is different e.g. {"a.b.c": "modified value"}

    Must not convert dicts to sets. Because of the billions of records that will be compared,
    conversion to sets, then back to dicts would drastically slow down the process.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.depth = []
        self.results = []

    def added(self, old, new):
        for key in new:
            if key not in old:
                if self.depth:
                    self.results.append({
                        'operation': 'ADDED',
                        'field': '.'.join(self.depth) + '.' + str(key),
                        'new': new[key]
                    })
                else:
                    self.results.append({
                        'operation': 'ADDED',
                        'field': str(key),
                        'new': new[key]
                    })
            else:
                if type(old[key]) == dict and type(new[key]) == dict:
                    self.depth.append(str(key))
                    self.added(old[key], new[key])

        if self.depth:
            self.depth.pop()
        else:
            return self.results

    def modified(self, old, new):
        for key in [key for key in new if key in old]:
            if type(old[key]) == dict and type(new[key]) == dict:
                self.depth.append(str(key))
                self.modified(old[key], new[key])

            elif old[key] != new[key]:
                if self.depth:
                    self.results.append({
                        'operation': 'MODIFIED',
                        'field': '.'.join(self.depth) + '.' + str(key),
                        'old': old[key],
                        'new': new[key]
                    })
                else:
                    self.results.append({
                        'operation': 'MODIFIED',
                        'field': str(key),
                        'old': old[key],
                        'new': new[key]
                    })

        if self.depth:
            self.depth.pop()
        else:
            return self.results

    def deleted(self, old, new):
        for key in old:
            if key not in new:
                if self.depth:
                    self.results.append({
                        'operation': 'DELETED',
                        'field': '.'.join(self.depth) + '.' + str(key),
                        'old': old[key]
                    })
                else:
                    self.results.append({
                        'operation': 'DELETED',
                        'field': str(key),
                        'old': old[key]
                    })
            else:
                if type(old[key]) == dict and type(new[key]) == dict:
                    self.depth.append(str(key))
                    self.deleted(old[key], new[key])

        if self.depth:
            self.depth.pop()
        else:
            return self.results

    def combine_results(self, old, new):
        self.added(old, new)
        self.modified(old, new)
        self.deleted(old, new)
        return self.results

    def difference(self, old, new):
        d = {}
        d['difference'] = self.combine_results(old, new)
        return d
```

Here is the unittest

```
import unittest
from diff import Diff

class TestDiff(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.old_dict = {"dict1":{"dict2": {"x":"A","z":"d"}}}
        self.new_dict = {"dict1":{"dict2": {"x":"C","y":"B"}}}
        self.old_flat = {"a":"a", "z":"z"}
        self.new_flat = {"a":"f", "b":"b"}

        self.d = Diff()

    def test_added_logic(self):
        result = self.d.added(self.old_dict, self.new_dict)
        expected = [{"operation": "ADDED", "field": "dict1.dict2.y", "new": "B"}]
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)

    def test_added_flat_dict(self):
        result = self.d.added(self.old_flat, self.new_flat)
        expected = [{'field': 'b', 'operation': 'ADDED', 'new': 'b'}]
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)

    def test_modified_logic(self):
        result = self.d.modified(self.old_dict, self.new_dict)
        expected = [{"operation": "MODIFIED", "field": "dict1.dict2.x", "old": "A", "new": "C"}]
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)

    def test_modified_flat_dict(self):
        result = self.d.modified(self.old_flat, self.new_flat)
        expected = [{'field': 'a', 'operation': 'MODIFIED', 'new': 'f', 'old': 'a'}]
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)

    def test_deleted_logic(self):
        result = self.d.deleted(self.old_dict, self.new_dict)
        expected = [{"operation": "DELETED", "field": "dict1.dict2.z", "old": "d"}]
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)

    def test_deleted_flat_dict(self):
        result = self.d.deleted(self.old_flat, self.new_flat)
        expected = [{'field': 'z', 'operation': 'DELETED', 'old': 'z'}]
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)

    def test_difference_logic(self):
        result = self.d.combine_results(self.old_dict, self.new_dict)
        expected = [
            {"operation": "ADDED", "field": "dict1.dict2.y", "new": "B"},
            {"operation": "MODIFIED", "field": "dict1.dict2.x", "old": "A", "new": "C"},
            {"operation": "DELETED", "field": "dict1.dict2.z", "old": "d"}
        ]
        self.assertEqual(result, expected)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Suggestion to simplify a part of it: `'field': ('.'.join(self.depth) + '.' if depth else '') + str(key)`

Answer (score 0):

based on @mike-k answer I made a method which does not need a new class to be made

## Implementation

```
def dict_diff(dict1: dict, dict2: dict, operation='modified', keys=None):
    """
    method to find the difference between (nested) dicts

    :param dict1: first dict to compare
    :param dict2: second dict to compare
    :param method: in ('added', 'deleted', 'modified')
        'added' checks for keys in `dict2` which do not occur in `dict1`
        'deleted' checks for keys in `dict1` which do not occur in `dict2`
        'modified' checks for all changes
    :param keys: this method uses recursion to check in nested dicts. `keys` is a list of the levels in the nesting
        does not need to be specified by the used
    :return: a sorted list of the differences between `dict1` and `dict2` in the form of a list of namedtuples
        namedtuple('DictDiffResult', ('key', 'dict1_value', 'dict2_value', 'operation'))
            `key` is a list of the keys of the changed element
            `operation` is  in ('added', 'deleted', 'modified')
    """
    acceptable_methods = ('added', 'deleted', 'modified')
    if operation not in acceptable_methods:
        raise ValueError('parameter `operation` should be on of %s' % str(acceptable_methods))
    dict_diff_result = namedtuple('DictDiffResult', ('key', 'dict1_value', 'dict2_value', 'operation'))
    if keys is None:
        keys = list()
    diffs = list()
    dict1_keyset = set(dict1)
    dict2_keyset = set(dict2)
    in_dict1_and_dict2 = dict1_keyset & dict2_keyset
    in_dict1_but_not_dict2 = sorted(dict1_keyset - in_dict1_and_dict2)
    in_dict2_but_not_dict1 = sorted(dict2_keyset - in_dict1_and_dict2)

    for key in sorted(in_dict1_and_dict2):
        key_list = keys + [key]

        dict1_val = dict1[key]
        dict2_val = dict2[key]
        if isinstance(dict1_val, dict) and isinstance(dict2_val, dict):
            results = dict_diff(dict1_val, dict2_val, keys=key_list, operation=operation)
            diffs += results
        elif dict1_val != dict2_val and operation == 'modified':
            diffs.append(dict_diff_result(key_list, dict1_val, dict2_val, 'modified'))
    if in_dict1_but_not_dict2 and operation in ('deleted', 'modified',):
        diffs += [dict_diff_result(keys + [key], dict1[key], None, 'deleted') for key in in_dict1_but_not_dict2]
    if in_dict2_but_not_dict1 and operation in ('added', 'modified',):
        diffs += [dict_diff_result(keys + [key], None, dict2[key], 'added') for key in in_dict2_but_not_dict1]

    return diffs
```

If you want a bit more performance but can do without the sorting you can drop the `sorted()` or implement this method using `yield` instead of `return` to get a `generator` instead of a `list`

## Doctest

```
"""
    >>> dict1 = {"key1":{"key2": {'a': 1, "x":"A","z":"d"}}, 'key3': 1, }
    >>> dict2 = {"key1":{"key2": {'a': 1, "x":"C","y":"B"}}, 'key4': 1, }

    >>> dict_diff(dict1, dict2) # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
    [DictDiffResult(key=['key1', 'key2', 'x'], dict1_value='A', dict2_value='C', operation='modified'),
    DictDiffResult(key=['key1', 'key2', 'z'], dict1_value='d', dict2_value=None, operation='deleted'),
    DictDiffResult(key=['key1', 'key2', 'y'], dict1_value=None, dict2_value='B', operation='added'),
    DictDiffResult(key=['key3'], dict1_value=1, dict2_value=None, operation='deleted'),
    DictDiffResult(key=['key4'], dict1_value=None, dict2_value=1, operation='added')]

    >>> dict_diff(dict1, dict1) # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
    []

    >>> dict_diff(dict1, dict2, operation='modified') # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
    [DictDiffResult(key=['key1', 'key2', 'x'], dict1_value='A', dict2_value='C', operation='modified'),
    DictDiffResult(key=['key1', 'key2', 'z'], dict1_value='d', dict2_value=None, operation='deleted'),
    DictDiffResult(key=['key1', 'key2', 'y'], dict1_value=None, dict2_value='B', operation='added'),
    DictDiffResult(key=['key3'], dict1_value=1, dict2_value=None, operation='deleted'),
    DictDiffResult(key=['key4'], dict1_value=None, dict2_value=1, operation='added')]

    >>> dict_diff(dict1, dict2, operation='deleted') # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
    [DictDiffResult(key=['key1', 'key2', 'z'], dict1_value='d', dict2_value=None, operation='deleted'),
    DictDiffResult(key=['key3'], dict1_value=1, dict2_value=None, operation='deleted')]

    >>> dict_diff(dict1, dict2, operation='added') # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
    [DictDiffResult(key=['key1', 'key2', 'y'], dict1_value=None, dict2_value='B', operation='added'),
    DictDiffResult(key=['key4'], dict1_value=None, dict2_value=1, operation='added')]

    >>> dict_diff(dict1, dict2, operation='wrong') # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE, +ELLIPSIS
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    ValueError: parameter `operation` should be on of ('added', 'deleted', 'modified')
"""
```

## Implementation without `set`

If you really need an implementation without `set` you could do the following

```
def dict_diff(dict1: dict, dict2: dict, operation='modified', keys=None):
    acceptable_methods = ('added', 'deleted', 'modified')
    if operation not in acceptable_methods:
        raise ValueError('parameter `operation` should be on of %s' % str(acceptable_methods))
    dict_diff_result = namedtuple('DictDiffResult', ('key', 'dict1_value', 'dict2_value', 'operation'))
    if keys is None:
        keys = list()
    diffs = list()

    for key in dict1:
        key_list = keys + [key]
        if key not in dict2:
            if operation in ('deleted', 'modified',):
                diffs.append(dict_diff_result(keys + [key], dict1[key], None, 'deleted'))
        else:
            dict1_val = dict1[key]
            dict2_val = dict2[key]
            if isinstance(dict1_val, dict) and isinstance(dict2_val, dict):
                results = dict_diff(dict1_val, dict2_val, keys=key_list, operation=operation)
                diffs += results
            elif dict1_val != dict2_val and operation == 'modified':
                diffs.append(dict_diff_result(key_list, dict1_val, dict2_val, 'modified'))
    for key in dict2:
        if key not in dict1:
            if operation in ('added', 'modified',):
                diffs.append(dict_diff_result(keys + [key], None, dict2[key], 'added'))

    return diffs
```

Since this iterates over the whole of dict2 this might be slower for long dicts with a lot of similar values

A minor detail about the second method is that it isn't sorted any more, but that can be changed quite easily